# Jenkins: Out of memory issue

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Suddenly I have started getting following error from integration test cases. Using Java 8 so I added MAVEN_OPTS = `-Xmx512m`. But it did not work. What am I missing here and how can I fix it? Between it works fine on local machine.

```
SUREFIRE-859: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000c9800000, 54001664, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 54001664 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
```

Comment: The option is actually `-Xmx512m`, aren't you missing the `-`?

Comment: `-` is there. It's a typo. Let me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, it looks like Java was not able to allocate enough memory, i.e. it's not Java's heap limit that's in the way but rather no more memory available to be given to Java by OS. Check that the machine is not running out of memory.

Comment: Thanks. How can I check that on Ubuntu?